# How to isolate this variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$m \cdot (a - b) + c = a$$

I can't figure out how to isolate $a$ in the equation above. I can't seem to detach $m$ so that $a$ can be left alone. What steps are required to isolate $a$?

Comment: Is anything given about m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expand and group the $a$ terms together. Let us first assume $m\ne 1$:
$$m(a-b)+c=a\\ma-mb+c=a\\ma-a=mb-c\\a(m-1)=mb-c\\a=\frac{mb-c}{m-1}$$
If $m=1$ we see that $0=b-c$ or $b=c$.

Answer (score 3):

$$m  (a - b) + c = a \Rightarrow \\ ma - a = mb - c \Rightarrow \\ a = \frac{mb-c}{m-1}$$

The last passage is valid only if $m \neq 1$, otherwise the denominator turns to be to $0$ (thanks to egreg for this). In that very special case, you should start from beginning, getting:
$$a-b +c = a\Rightarrow \\
b = c.$$

This means that if you want $m=1$, then you must also have $b=c$, otherwise $a$ can't be calculated.

To understand this, take $m=1$, $b = 2$ and $c=3$. Then:

$$1 \cdot (a - 2) + 3 = a \Rightarrow \\
a-a-2+3 = 0 \Rightarrow \\
1 = 0...$$

Comment: For $m\ne 1$ $\quad$

Comment: @egreg yeah, that's important, really forgot about it

Answer (score 1):

First, expand the first term to get $ma-mb+c=a$. Now the key is to get all the terms involving $a$ together; this requires that you move the $ma$ term to the right side by subtracting to get $-mb+c=a-ma$. You can then pull out the $a$ term to get $-mb+c=a(1-m)$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute $m*(a-b)= ma -mb$.  The get all $a$'s on the same side.  You now have $a-ma = -mb + c$.  Factor out $a$ from the left side to get $a * (1-m) = c - mb$.  Now divide and you get $a = \frac{c-mb}{1-m}$